# I am doing a fiizzBuzz array and I keep getting a null before my array

Tags: java, arrays, fizzbuzz

```
public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end) {
int end1 = end - start;
String [] new1 = new String[end]; 
for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
  if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
  {
    new1[i] = "FizzBuzz";
  }
  else if(i % 3 == 0)
  {
    new1[i] = "Fizz";
  }
  else if (i % 5 == 0)
  {
    new1[i] = "Buzz";
  }
  else
  {
    new1[i] = Integer.toString(i);
  }
}
return new1;
}
```

EXAMPLE:

Expected:

```
fizzBuzz(1, 6) → ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz"]
```

Result:

```
[null, "1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz"]
```

Comment: Arrays indices start from 0. Calling `fizzBuzz(1, 6)` will start iteration at index 1.

Comment: @Li357 I think that your comment answers the question very well. If you decide to write it as an official answer, other users will be able to find it more easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function `fizzBuzz(1, 6)`, the last condition i.e, `new1[i] = Integer.toString(i);` will be executed. where i = 1 which is the second index of array `new1` since array indexes start from 0. So obviously, the first index of the array i.e,`new[0]` is null.